# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. alan_voice:compileReleaseKotlin'. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

[image]

I tried to change the ext.kotlin_version but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `flutter upgrade` or `flutter upgrade --force` and then `flutter run -v`

Otherwise take a look at this : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49438

Comment: Not working for me :(